# Rubymine: How do i make it so that when i type # in double quoted string, it auto fills #{}

Tags: rubymine

When i'm in a double quoted string

if i type #, I would like rubymine to autofill with #{cursor_here}

which would allow me to type first_name inside and then tab out of the brackets so i can quickly keep typing.

```
first_name = "Mark"
sentence = "Hi my name is #{first_name}"
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.

Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys |

Under the Ruby section, check the box "Start ruby interpolation in strings on #.